# Pandas groupby calculate difference

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['2017-09-30','A',123],['2017-12-31','A',23],['2017-09-30','B',74892],['2017-12-31','B',52222],['2018-09-30','A',37599],['2018-12-31','A',66226]]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data,columns=["Date", "Company", "Revenue YTD"])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = df.groupby(['Company',df['Date'].dt.year]).diff()
print(df)


     Date  Revenue YTD
0     NaT          NaN
1 92 days       -100.0
2     NaT          NaN
3 92 days     -22670.0
4     NaT          NaN
5 92 days      28627.0
```

I would like to calculate the company's revenue difference by September and December. I have tried with groupby company and year. But the result is not what I am expecting

Expecting result

```
     Date         Company   Revenue YTD
0    2017            A           -100
1    2018            A         -22670
2    2017            B          28627
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this should work

```
(df.assign(Date=df['Date'].dt.year,
           Revenue_Diff=df.groupby(['Company',df['Date'].dt.year])['Revenue YTD'].diff())
   .drop('Revenue YTD', axis=1)
   .dropna()
)
```

Output:

```
   Date Company  Revenue_Diff
1  2017       A        -100.0
3  2017       B      -22670.0
5  2018       A       28627.0
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

Set it up:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['2017-09-30','A',123],['2017-12-31','A',23],['2017-09-30','B',74892],['2017-12-31','B',52222],['2018-09-30','A',37599],['2018-12-31','A',66226]]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data,columns=["Date", "Company", "Revenue YTD"])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

---

Update with `np.diff()`:

```
my_func = lambda x: np.diff(x)

df = (df.groupby([df.Date.dt.year, df.Company])
         .agg({'Revenue YTD':my_func}))

print(df)

              Revenue YTD
Date Company
2017 A               -100
     B             -22670
2018 A              28627
```

Hope this helps.